# Cursor moving to initial position when press a key in Editable Combo WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application, there is an editable combo box. On Combo_KeyUp Event I'm binding the itemsource for this combo box. When I key in this box, the cursor is moving to initial position(Back to starting of the text and continues). Please help me to [resolve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzfoo.png) this.

Answer (score 0):

Do the binding in your `KeyUp`-Handler only if the `ItemsSource` for your `ComboBox` is null.